# What's the best way to store metadata about the cells in a table (string[][])?

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript

I'm building an npm package to replace the built-in console.table() function in javascript. Basically, my code takes in a 2D string array (string[][]) and returns a new formatted string[][] with borders, padded strings, etc...

As I perform these modifications to the array, it's important to keep track of what **type** of cell is at each index. For example, when borders are added to the table, the indices of the cells with **borders** need to be distinct from those with the actual **data**. This is complicated by the fact that borders can be added between columns and rows, and the content of cells may **overflow** which requires adding extra "overflow" rows. The indices of these overflow rows must also be tracked because I need to ensure borders aren't added between them and their "primary" row.

So, what is the best way to store all this metadata about the cells?

To be clear, I have a solution that works, but I'm curious to see if someone can think of a better option.

**Here's my current solution:**

I have a separate class, called SignificantIndices, which stores a number[][] that represents a set of indices in the table (Table.table). Whenever I add rows and columns to the original table, I just update all the instances of SignificantIndices using addIndex() which will automatically shift any other indices in that array by one, to match those of the original table. I can also just use the shift() method if a row is added to the table, but it isn't being tracked by that specific instance of SignificantIndices.

```
class Table {
  table: string[][];
  options: TableOptions;
  overFlowRowIdxs: SignificantIndicesType = new SignificantIndices();
  borderRowIdxs: SignificantIndicesType = new SignificantIndices();
  borderColumnsIdxs: SignificantIndicesType = new SignificantIndices();
  // ...
}

class SignificantIndices {
  indices: number[][]

  addIndex(idx: number) {
    // If its the first insertion, just push it and return
    if (this.indices.length === 0) {
      this.indices.push(idx);
      return;
    }

    // Find the position to insert the new idx while maintaining the order
    const position = this.indices.findIndex((element) => element >= idx);
    if (position === -1) {
      this.indices.push(idx);
    } else {
      this.indices.splice(position, 0, idx);
      // Update the indices greater than the inserted idx
      for (let i = position + 1; i < this.indices.length; i++) {
        this.indices[i]++;
      }
    }
  }

  shiftIndices(idx: number, shift: number) {
    // Shift all indices at or greater than idx by shift
    for (let i = idx; i < this.indices.length; i++) {
      this.indices[i] += shift;
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

My current implementation feels super clunky because it requires me to manually update all instances of the SignificantIndices class whenever I add rows or columns to the table. I would like them to just automatically update whenever the table updates.

**Here are some ideas I've had:**

- I'm actually face-palming as I'm typing this because I didn't think of this until now... The table could just be an **array of objects**, each with a "data" property and a "type" property... duh. Well I'm probably just going to do this, but I'm still posting this to see if people can make an argument for a better solution :)
- Observer pattern: table is observable and any set of indices I'm tracking are observers
- I could store a map, where the key is the index and the value is the type of cell at that index